# How to fix IE select issue when dynamically changing options

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs, html-select

I have a set of selects that all have the same options. Then I run those options through a filter so that any options that are selected in a different select don't show up in the select. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H48sP/1/) (in non-IE browser) to see what I mean. Basically I'm preventing the same option from being selected multiple times among the selects

Now, what I've done has an issue in IE. Open that fiddle in IE (I've only tried it in IE9, but I'm guessing previous versions have the same issue). Change the last select to AAA. Notice how the 3 other selects all changed what they display. The model for them did not change, but IE somehow chokes when the options are changed.

My questions is first, am I doing something wrong with this functionality in general? This same code does exactly what I want in Chrome and FF, but am I doing something that I just shouldn't be? Second, how can I get around this in IE? I tried some timeouts that would clear and re-set the model, but things noticeable jumped around. I'm wondering if there's a good, clean, low impact workaround for this.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**--UPDATE--**

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6604c2361427fba8c43a39dc2e92197390dfbdbe) in Angular itself with [version 1.3.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#133-undersea-arithmetic-2014-11-17) using [A. S. Ranjan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25310374/1014979) below. See new fiddle with 1.3.3: http://jsfiddle.net/m2ytyapv/

```
//dummy code so I can post the edit
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: I did not. I've put it off for now, but I'll need something at some point.

Comment: There has already been an issue raised for an issue similiar to this.. Have a look at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1902

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've finally come up with a solution that works for my needs. Basically what appears to be happening is that the text for the option at the selected index is pointing to the old string that used to be in that place. I believe changing this text updates the strings and/or references. I did something like this:

```
angular.forEach($("select"), function (currSelect) {
     currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].text += " ";
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H48sP/35/

In my app, I have a directive where these selects are, and so I do `element.find("select")` instead of `$("select")` to limit the scope of the element selecting. The text is forced to refresh and so displays correctly after all the digest cycles run.

If you have run into this same issue, you may need to add a `$timeout` like in the fiddle, and/or you may need to later remove the extra space that was added to the option text if that becomes a problem.

Answer (score 29):

I experienced the same issue the other night and after throwing everything I could think of at it I've come to the conclusion that IE just doesn't want to handle updating filters when using selects.

My solution is to change your selects to look like this:

```
 <select class="selectList" ng-repeat="currId in selectedIds" ng-model="selectedIds[$index]"  ng-options="currOption.id as currOption.value for currOption in myObj | myfilter:selectedIds:$index" data-ng-change="fixIE()"></select>
```

They now have a class and an ng-change on them. Then in your controller do this fun little bit of code:

```
$scope.fixIE = function(){
    //code to check if IE so the other browsers don't get this ugly hack.
    var selectLists = document.querySelectorAll(".selectList");
    for(var x = 0;x  < selectLists.length; x++){
        selectLists[x].parentNode.insertBefore(selectLists[x], selectLists[x]);
    }       
};
```

What it does is rip the elements out of the DOM and replace them into the same location. Here's a working fiddle **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H48sP/32/)**

Some of the other solutions I tried that didn't involve javascript were things like toggling the display/visibility of the select. Having their zIndex's moved. The only thing that for sure fixed it was this piece of code.

Comment: That definitely works in the jsFiddle. Unfortunately, in my app, where there's a lot more going on, it still has the problem. What is interesting is that something as simple as adding a console log (http://jsfiddle.net/H48sP/33/) breaks it again. It seems like any workaround for this will be very fragile. I'm hoping your answer will lead me to a permanent solution. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Can you post more of what your problem is then? I'm not sure what else could be going on that would limit the filters. If you could post an updated fiddle with the issue I can take a look. The code is not fragile, just ugly :)

Comment: Hmmm.... so I was thinking of ways to "break" this method. The one I have come to is if the filter is updating slowly before the ng-change has fired. It would reattach the elements before it needs too. If that's the case, a $timeout might help. Perhaps calling this function on your own when you know there's going to be an issue (not necessarily on ng-change) might help.

Comment: In my app the data model is very complicated. I don't think I could reproduce it in a fiddle. However, you did get me on the right track to my final solution, so I will gladly award you the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: Best of luck, if you can you accept the answer to so it moves to the top? I have a feeling a lot of people will have this issue.

Comment: This worked for me, while the accepted answer didn't. Had the exact same problem with dynamic selects not re-rendering properly in IE.

Comment: I've voted up and added one edit that use this solution as a directive. By the way: bad, bad IE!

Comment: GREAT!! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 20):

I have the fix.

We have to add and remove options list to trigger the rendering in IE8.

http://kkurni.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/angularjs-ng-option-with-ie8.html

---

```
/**
 * Fix for IE select menus getting stuck when their underlying list changes.
 * Original code: http://kkurni.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/angularjs-ng-option-with-ie8.html
 * 
 * Set the `ie-select-fix` attribute to the model expression that should trigger the list to re-render.
 * 
 * @example <select ng-model="modelValue" ie-select-fix="itemList" ng-options="item.label for item in itemList">
 */
app.directive('ieSelectFix', ['$document',
        function($document) {

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelCtrl) {
                    var isIE = $document[0] && $document[0].attachEvent;
                    if (!isIE) return;

                    var control = element[0];
                    //to fix IE8 issue with parent and detail controller, we need to depend on the parent controller
                    scope.$watch(attributes.ieSelectFix, function() {
                        // setTimeout is needed starting from angular 1.3+
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            //this will add and remove the options to trigger the rendering in IE8
                            var option = document.createElement("option");
                            control.add(option,null);
                            control.remove(control.options.length-1);
                        }, 0);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem for me without any issues. I'd recommend adding your code into your answer here for future readers.

Comment: Great work!  This works perfectly.  We had some performance issues with the solution that uses $timeout when used in ngRepeat with a lot of items.  Going this way resolved that.

Comment: this is a clearer, complete solution, solved by copy/paste . also it works in ie8.

Comment: This worked well for me. I like that it is a simple directive and fits natively with Angular rather than jquery hacks.

Comment: Awesome work. I've been pulling my hair out the past 2 days trying to work around this issue, and you're solution worked perfectly. This needs to be the accepted answer because it's done the proper way -- with a directive that actually listens for model changes.

Comment: One thing I'd like to add is that the above fix will not work the first time a select is rendered if that select is inside a container  using ng-if. Using a $timeout inside the watch will correct that.

Comment: Works great. For JsLint purists, the creation and addition of the option with `document` in the watch function can be replaced by appending a new option with `element.append('<option/>');`

Comment: This worked perfectly with angular-1.2, but when upgraded to angular-1.3 i had to wrap DOM manipulation in a `setTimeout(fn, 0)`

Comment: Why does it require ngModel, include it as a parameter, and then not use it anywhere?  The fix seems to work correctly without it.

Answer (score 5):

Adding couple of lines the following places (marked in bold as **) in render function of the selectDirective in angular.js worked fine for me.  I am looking if there is any other possible solution other than patching angularJS or the forEach given below?

```
            if (existingOption.label !== option.label) {
              lastElement.text(existingOption.label = option.label);
              **lastElement.attr('label', existingOption.label);**
            }
```

and

```
              (element = optionTemplate.clone())
                  .val(option.id)
                  .attr('selected', option.selected)
                  .text(option.label);
              **element.attr('label', option.label);**
```

The issue was the label attribute of HTMLOptionElement is not the same as the text attribute if label is blank in IE.

This can be seen verified by adding the following code after the screen has loaded and looking at the web console of FF and IE to see the difference.  If you uncomment the last line where the label is set to text it works fine.  Alternatively patch angular.js as above.

```
// This is an IE fix for not updating the section of dropdowns which has ng-options with filters
angular.forEach($("select"), function (currSelect) {
    console.log("1.text ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].text);
    console.log("1.label ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].label);
    //console.log("1.innerHTML ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
    //console.log("1.textContent ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].textContent);
    //console.log("1.cN.data ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].childNodes[0].data);
    //console.log("1.cN.nodeValue ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    //console.log("1.cN.textContent ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].childNodes[0].textContent);
    //console.log("1.cN.wholeText ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].childNodes[0].wholeText);
    //console.log("1. ", currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex], "\n");

    //currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].label = "xyz";
    //currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].label = currSelect.options[currSelect.selectedIndex].text;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be related to the order of the options returned by the filter. When you change the last option to `A`, the other select options changes. What seems to cause a problem for IE is that the selected option changes place. In the first select box `C` is selected from the options in the following order: `A, B, C, D`. The selected option is the **third option**. When you change the forth select box from `G` to `A`, the filter changes the options in the first box to `B, C, D, G`. The selected option is now the **second option**, and this causes a problem with IE. This might be a bug in Angular, or it might be to some strange behavior in IE. I've created a fork that works around this by making sure that selected element is always the first option from the filtered options:

```js
   var newOptions = [],selected;
    angular.forEach(allOptions, function (currentOption) {
        if (!isIdInUse(selectedIds, currentOption.id)){
            newOptions.push(currentOption);
        }else if(currentOption.id == selectedIds[parseInt(index)]){
            selected = currentOption;
        }
    });
    if(selected){newOptions.unshift(selected);}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XhxSD/ (old)

Update:

I did some debugging and found the line that causes problems in IE, but I don't understand why. It does seem like a rendering bug or something. I've created another workaround that doesn't require any rearranging of the options - it's a directive that watches for changes on the select element. If a change is detected it appends an option and removes it immediately:

```js
.directive('ieSelectFix',function($timeout){
  return {
    require:'select',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      var isIE = document.attachEvent;

      if(isIE){
        $timeout(function(){
          var index = element.prop('selectedIndex'), children = element.children().length;
          scope.$watch(function(){
            if(index !== element.prop('selectedIndex') || children !== element.children().length){
              index = element.prop('selectedIndex');
              children = element.children().length;
              var tmp =angular.element('<option></option>');
              element.append(tmp);
              tmp.remove();
            }
          })

        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Just add ie-select-fix to select elements inside ng-repeats:

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ie-select-fix ng-repeat="currId in selectedIds" ng-model="selectedIds[$index]"  ng-options="currOption.id as currOption.value for currOption in myObj | myfilter:selectedIds:$index"></select><br>
  {{selectedIds}}
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VgpyZ/ (new)

Comment: This is certainly a workaround, but I'm not sure I can have the selected option always going to the top.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your updated answer until after I awarded the bounty. This looks along the same lines of what I ended up doing.

Comment: That solution resolved my bug in ie11. Choosing from two selects after some changes has stopped working. Now it works well. @joakimbl Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

i've found the same bug in IE with select's.. this bug is the result of cloning DOM nodes..

if you instantiating a SELECT like (jQuery style):

```
$select = $template.clone();
```

and then doing:

```
$select.html('<option>111</option>');
```

you'll get the bug, described above..

BUT, if you instantiate

```
$select = $('< div />').html( $template ).html();
```

no bugs occurred :)

Comment: This way works for me only if I am creating the div separately: `var tempDiv = $('<div>'); var newSelect = $(tempDiv.html($template).html());`

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I'm going to hell for the following advice...!

I tried these suggestions, but none worked for me.

I was actually using Angular to populate select controls with multiple options in each.

```
<select class="cssMultipleSelect" multiple="multiple" ...>
```

Sometimes, Angular would populate these controls, the new data would appear, but in IE, you couldn't scroll up and down to view all of the options.

But, if you hit F12, modified the width, and put it back to its original width, then IE would burst back into life again, and you could scroll up and down in the list of values.

So, my solution was to call this, a second or so after Angular had finished populating the controls:

```
function RefreshMultipleSelectControls()
{
    //  A dodgy fix to an IE11 issue.
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".cssMultipleSelect").width("");
    }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".cssMultipleSelect").width(298);
    }, 1600);
}
```

(I told you this was a dodgy fix..)

One other thing: remember that in IE11, `navigator.appName` will now return `NETSCAPE` (rather than `MSIE` or `Microsoft Internet Explorer`)...  so be careful when you're testing if your code is running on IE, or on a decent browser.

You've been warned..!!

Comment: This worked for me without the delay. Just using setTimeout was enough. 

`setTimeout(function () {
        $(".cssMultipleSelect").width("");
    }, 0);
`

Answer (score 0):

Seems that ie9 have problem with the index. Taking the second example and change it to the following code it worked:

```
  var hwcalcModule = angular.module('ie9select', []);

  function AnimalCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.categories = [{
        name: "Cats",
        kinds: ["Lion", "Leopard", "Puma"]
    }, {
        name: "Dogs",
        kinds: ["Chihua-Hua", " Yorkshire Terrier", "Pitbull"]
    }];

  $scope.animals = [{
      category: $scope.categories[1],
      kind: $scope.categories[1].kinds[1]
  }];

  $scope.changeCategory = function (animal) {
      console.log(animal.category.name);
      var name = animal.category.name;
      var index = 0;
       angular.forEach($scope.categories, function (currentOption) {
           console.log(currentOption.name);
          if (name == currentOption.name)
          {
              console.log(index);
              $scope.animals = [{
                  category: $scope.categories[index],
                  kind: $scope.categories[index].kinds[0]
              }];
           }
           index++;
       });
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/seoservice/nFp62/10/

Comment: That appears to make the fiddle linked in the GitHub issue work, but I'm having trouble applying the solution to my use case. That one is through the `ng-change` whereas all my stuff happens in a filter. If you can create a working fiddle from the one linked in my question, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: hm... your problem is more setting the selected options into the dropdown. Leaving the dropdown without the selected value it's working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/H48sP/9/

Comment: Yeah, however, I do need the dropdown with the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

On the lines of  [Mathew Berg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16543440/922929) answer, I modified it to work using AngularJS directive:

```
angular.module('select',[]).directive("select", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      require: "?ngModel",
      scope: false,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        if (!ngModel) {
          return;
        }

        element.bind("change", function() {
            //Fix for IE9 where it is not able to properly handle dropdown value change
            //The fix is to rip out the dropdown from DOM and add it back at the same location
            if (isIE9){
                this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this);   //this rips the elements out of the DOM and replace it into the same location.
            }
        })
      }
   }
});
```

This way the fix applies to all `select` elements in the project and you do not have to change any existing HTML markup. I also used the following method to detect IE version to set `isIE9` variable to `true`:

```
var Browser = {
    IsIE: function () {
        return navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1;
    },
    Navigator: navigator.appVersion,
    Version: function() {
        var version = 999; // we assume a sane browser
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1)
            // bah, IE again, lets downgrade version number
            version = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]);
        return version;
    }
};

var oldIE = false;      //Global Variable
var isIE9 = false;      //Global Variable
if (Browser.IsIE && Browser.Version() <= 8) {
    oldIE = true;
}

if (Browser.IsIE && Browser.Version() == 9) {
    isIE9 = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change scope.$watch to scope.$watchCollection to make @kkurni solution above to work for IE9. Just wanted to help others out who were still having issues in IE9 for rendering select options when they change.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering gets updated and synched if you change some attribute. An innocuous change may be to set the `selectedIndex` attribute to its own value:

```
function fixIEselect() {
    for (var nForm = 0; nForm < document.forms.length; ++nForm) {
        var form = document.forms[nForm];
        var children = form.children;
        for (var nChild = 0; nChild < children.length; ++nChild) {
            var child = children.item(nChild);
            if (child.tagName == "SELECT") {
                alert("Fixed: " + child.name);
                child.selectedIndex = child.selectedIndex; // dummy nop but not
            }
        }
    }
}

fixIEselect();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is less expensive way to enforce control re-rendering after dynamic options are added.
So, instead of inserting/removing dummy element to the dropdown you can reset CSS styles which cause control rendering, e.g.

```
selElement.style.zoom = selElement.style.zoom ? "" : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for the IE picklist issue

Before Fix:http://plnkr.co/edit/NGwG1LUVk3ctGOsX15KI?p=preview

After Fix:http://plnkr.co/edit/a7CGJavo2m2Tc73VR28i?p=preview

```
$("select").click(function(){
  $(this).append('<option></option>');
   $(this).find('option:last').remove();

});
```

I just added dummy option for the dom to rerender the select and removed it. 
let me know it works for you