# IE10 with select using ng-options with no default value set in model always selects first element in dropdown

Tags: angularjs, select, internet-explorer-10

I am using Angular v1.0.8

I have a select and I am using ng-options directive to populate it with an array of data declared in my Controller.

HTML snippet

```
<body ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
  <select 
    ng-model="selected" 
    ng-options="o as o.caption for o in options" />
</body>
```

Code snippet

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('SelectCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.options = [
      { key: 1, caption: '1' },
      { key: 2, caption: '2' },
      { key: 3, caption: '3' },
      { key: 4, caption: '4' },
      { key: 5, caption: '5' }
    ];

}]);
```

In Chrome, if you select let's say option `3` then, as expected, it gets selected.

In IE10, however, if you select option `3` then option `1` gets selected.

(http://plnkr.co/edit/T9bbEW?p=preview)

This only happens when there is no default selection set in the controller. And subsequent selections done after the "blank" choice is removed gets set correctly.

I suspect that it might possibly be a duplicate of [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942681/how-to-fix-ie-select-issue-when-dynamically-changing-options) but I am not entirely sure. I am not really dynamically changing the options here although I suppose maybe Angular is since the "blank" choice are getting removed in both browsers.

I do however want this functionality. I don't want to provide a default value for this select because the user needs to make an active choice for me.

Does anyone know a workaround and/or solution for this? Preferably one that does not involve messing with the options using JQuery...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The blank item that angular adds has some odd behavior.  The way we've gotten around it is to explicitly add our own blank item and select it via the controller:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('SelectCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.options = [
    { key: 0, caption: ' ' },
    { key: 1, caption: '1' },
    { key: 2, caption: '2' },
    { key: 3, caption: '3' },
    { key: 4, caption: '4' },
    { key: 5, caption: '5' }
  ];

  $scope.selected = $scope.options[0]

}]);
```

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to do something like that. Good to know I'm not the only one doing it at least :)

Answer (score 2):

I fix this by adding following default option into select.

```
<option value="">Pls select</option>
```

so your select would look like this:

```
<body ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
<select 
  ng-model="selected" 
  ng-options="o as o.caption for o in options">
    <option value="">Pls select</option>
</select>
```

I tested this in IE 11, 10, 9 and it seems to be working.
Please let me know if it works for you as well.

I think this is cleaner than the above solution.

Comment: This works in IE9 & IE10 if your default option value does NOT need interpolation (ie. "Please select" works, "{{'Please select'}}" does not). Phil Sandler's solution with prepending an empty option to the array seems to do the job in this case.