# First selection of <select> element not working in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

We're seeing some really odd behaviour in IE when using the `ng-options` directive with a `select` element which are not happening when we use `<option ng-repeat=''>`.

The first time I select an option from the drop down box which was created using `ng-options`, whichever option I select, the first one is displayed.

If I use ng-repeat to create the options it works perfectly every time.

If I select an option from the "broken" drop down, then select an option from the not broken one, the first drop down box actually changes it's selected item to display the correct selection.

I'm using IE 11 and have got an example here showing the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/Q26mW/

Comment: I've had the same issue in IE10. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388030/ie10-with-select-using-ng-options-with-no-default-value-set-in-model-always-sele

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix it, I've tried it with a new fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Hr8S4/

Comment: That is because angular will use object-equality, you need to set the `ng-model` to an actual item in the array. See http://jsfiddle.net/V5U6P/1/

Comment: Of course, I set the initial value to null and not to the empty element. You should really get the bounty for this as you posted the first correct answer (all be it as a comment)

Comment: Give it to the guy who answered the question I linked then. That's where this workaround came from.

Comment: Or if Patrick's directive works for you, give it to him. I don't really care about rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a directive to handle this... I called it "empty-option":

```
myApp.directive("emptyOption", ["$timeout", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "^ngModel",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            //Get "SELECT" element of empty option
            var parentSelectDom = element[0].parentNode,
                removed = false;

            //Make sure the element is "SELECT" before proceeding.
            if (parentSelectDom.nodeName === "SELECT") {

                //When $modelValue changes, either add/remove empty option
                //based on whether or not $modelValue is defined.
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
                }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal === undefined) {
                        if (removed) {
                            $timeout(function () {
                                //Add empty option back to list.
                                parentSelectDom.add(element[0], parentSelectDom[0]);
                            }, 0);
                            removed = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!removed) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            //remove empty option.
                            parentSelectDom.remove(0);
                        }, 0);
                        removed = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

The directive allows for an empty option to be specified for a select. It removes the option when a selection is made and adds back the empty option when the model value is cleared.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q26mW/7/).

Comment: This works but I've got to give @ivarni the chance to claim the bounty as his answer (all be it a comment) was the first correct answer. If he's not bothered I'll award it to you tomorrow.

Comment: This is different than the one in the comment. The dropdown that "works" in your example removes the empty option when a selection is made. The blank value in the typeOptions array doesn't do that... Also, the directive allows you to make an option such as "-- choose a value --" that will disappear when a selection is made. If you want an empty option that doesn't disappear, just add it to the view and forget about needing to set it in the scope: http://jsfiddle.net/Q26mW/9/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution - it solves a different issue which occurred in  a WebView (think Cordova) on an iPhone. The problem we had was that on iOS we would see wrong value in the dropdown after making a selection (it would show the item with index+1). 
The only change I needed to make was replacing if(newVal === undefined)  with if(!newVal) <- I was getting newVal = null not undefined.

Answer (score 4):

I have found this is fixed in the latest version of angularJS >= 1.2.21

FIXED angular ver 1.2.21 - http://plnkr.co/edit/LJagDO6VgFORuU4vxQON?p=preview

Broken angular ver 1.2.20 -  http://plnkr.co/edit/I1dG9ShSw9bJspcu6R0l?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.users = [{
      name: 'John Doe',
      userName: 'jdoe'
    }, {
      name: 'Jane Smith',
      userName: 'jsmith'
    }, {
      name: 'Foo Bar',
      userName: 'foobar'
    }];
  });
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Angular IE9-IE11 Select Issue</h1>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model="data.selectedUser" ng-options="user.name for user in data.users"></select>
<div>Selected User:
  <label>{{data.selectedUser}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```