# IE8 / AngularJS dropdown layout issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

we've ran into a problem where the dropdowns, generated by Angular's ng-select, clip some of the text. IE8 only of course.

In the image, I disabled ALL styling, except for width: something !important. We need to do that otherwise you won't see anything in the dropdown.

[image: IE8 messing up dropdown]

The HTML for the option is just:

```
<option value="2">Obligatie</option>
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The underlying problem might be that IE8 does not work very well with ng-repeat. I'm looking into the fix for this question now: [Stackoverflow: how to fix IE select issue when dynamically changing options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942681/how-to-fix-ie-select-issue-when-dynamically-changing-options)

Turns out: we had this problem too, but it doesn't solve the layout issue.

Comment: does changing the line-height help?

Comment: Nope - tried it, doesn't seem to affect the dropdown

Comment: Can you share a runnable sample to demo the problem?

Comment: No I can't. JSFiddle does not support IE8...

Comment: Hmm, does Plunker work? I'm on IE11 and won't go back. NEVER!

Comment: Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/zGaW2UXltbV4F3bZiamz?p=preview and just for information tell us if it worked. Use it as base.

Comment: PLNKR doesn't work either, sorry. We're building this fox a bank that only recently switched from IE6 to IE8.... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

There are some branches that should know better than using IE8 in 2014: (Banks, Nuclear Power Plants, Thermonuclear-Warfare Whoprs, etc ...). But, hey, they do:-\

If this issue is related to a ng-repeat I can at least suggest to not use ng-repeat but ng-options.

Try this:

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in items"></select>
  </div>
```

Get the options from your scope:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.items = [
     { id: 1, name: 'Obligata' },
     { id: 2, name: 'Obligatie' },
     { id: 3, name: 'Obladoyah' }
   ];

    $scope.selectedItem=2;
};
```

Not sure if this helps. But it's worth a try.

Plunker with full code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/C3HufuWOGGO0o9p2s7Q2?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks - but that's exactly what I'm doing. <select> with ng-options. My colleague has created a fix where he waits 100ms and then uses jQuery to set the height. CSS height settings will not do the trick.