# internet explorer select dropdown collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

i have select dropdown which picks no. of pages to be shown as jquery pagination. everything is fine but when it comes to ie. select dropdown collapses.see image.[image: iedropdown]

i also refered [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775533/strange-ie11-form-fields-bug-after-selecting-from-dropdown)

but it seems it will not work for me.I am doubtful that is it ie default behaviour and can't do much....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      

    var url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/aaa/aaa/aaa";        
    url+="?fromDate=${fromDate}";
    url+="&toDate=${toDate}";
    url+="&callType=${callType}";
    url+="&fullListSize=0";
    var table = $('#call_history_detail').DataTable({
        "preDrawCallback": function( settings ) {
            $("#searchTable").val("");
            $('body').modalProgress("show");
        },
        "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            wordWrap("userName", 80, 2);
            $('body').modalProgress("hide");
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "searching": false,
        //"ajax": url,
        "ajax": {
                    "contentType": "application/json",
                    "url": url, 
                    "data": function ( d ) {
                        var drawValue = d.draw;
                        var length = d.length;
                        var start = d.start;
                        var sortCol = d.order[0].column;
                        var sortType = d.order[0].dir;

                          return "draw=" + drawValue + "&length=" + length + "&start=" + start + "&sortCol=" + sortCol + "&sortType=" + sortType;

                    }
            },
        "oLanguage": {
                         "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries. <img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/ico_info.png' class='tt'" +
                         "title='The search function will only search the page you are currently viewing.  To do a more expansive search, increase the entries per page.  Increasing the entries per page can increase load time.' />"
                     },
        "lengthMenu": [ [25, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000], [25, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000] ],
        "columns": [
            { "name": "userName" },
            { "name": "callType"},
            { "name": "date" },
            { "name": "time" },
            { "name": "from" },
            { "name": "to" },
            { "name": "cost", "width": "10%" },
            { "name": "duration", "width": "10%" }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "class": "userName",
                "data": "userName",
                "defaultContent": "",                   
                "targets": 0
            },
            {
                "class": "callType",
                "data": "callType",
                "defaultContent": "",
                "targets": 1
            },
            {
                "class": "date-time",
                "data": "timeStart",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return getShortDate(data);
                },
                "defaultContent": "",
                "targets": 2
            },
            {
                "class": "date-time",
                "data": "timeStart",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return getTimeString(data);
                },                   
                "defaultContent": "",
                "targets": 3
            },
            {
                "class": 'number',
                "data": "origNumber",
                "defaultContent": "",
                "orderable": true,
                "targets": 4
            },
            {
                "class": 'number',
                "data": "destNumber",
                "defaultContent": "",
                "orderable": true,
                "targets": 5
            },
            {
                "class": 'cost',
                "data": "totalAmount",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return "$"+data.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
                },
                "defaultContent": "",
                "targets": 6
            },
            {
                "class": 'duration',
                "data": "callDuration",
                "defaultContent": "00:00:00",
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": 7
            }

          ],

          "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]
    });
    $('#backToSummary').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('form#call-history-options').submit();
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: Post your code as well

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the css div z-index: value;

Comment: add z-index: positive values; into the drop down div