# Incorrect CSS rendering of side bar menu in IE8

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I tried to fix this error in my view for IE8. 
Sorry if this question has been asked many times before ,but I still can't solve it.

This is my plunker:
[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/aBrxuAX0Mn1vxTPjEAO7?p=preview)

When I run this plunker in IE8 the menu is hidden by default.

[image]

If you want to see in IE 
[Plunk full view](http://run.plnkr.co/Wq9x0uSTiSIqYC3g/)

This is the design of the real system running in IE8, there is extra space that shouldn't be there between the menu and the content.

[image]

As you can see the picture:

- A I have extra space that shouldn't be there
- B My add-ons look correctly aligned only in firefox
- C I was able to fix the select using a directive found here [kkurni.blogspot.com.au](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942681/how-to-fix-ie-select-issue-when-dynamically-changing-options) posted by kkurni

To fix Angular.js problem I tried this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="yeomanTutAngApp">
 <head>
     <!--[if lte IE 8]>
     <script>
       document.createElement('ng-view');
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
</head>
</html>

 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-model="selected" id= "mySearch"
    typeahead="word for word in getAutocomplete($viewValue)" 
    typeahead- `loading`="loadingClientsPreview">
    <i ng-show="loadingClientsPreview" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove input-group-addon" ng-click="selected = ''"></span></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

C. My select shows data, but this looks too small. (Fixed)

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <p class="col-xs-3 ">{{'Language'|translate}}</p>
     <select ng-model="people.language"
          ng-options="value.code as value.name | translate for value in languages">
     </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a normalize.css ? If not, add the following CSS inside your

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/