# IE has stopped working

Tags: internet-explorer

I am having multiple drop downs with on change event.

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

While changing the option IE11 has stopped working on drop down change event. How to fix it?

Comment: did this https://jsfiddle.net/f1vghLdn/  in ie11 and it appears to work

Answer (score 0):

> The onchange event does not fire when the selected option of the
>   select object is changed programmatically.

Source : [change | onchange event - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(VS.85).aspx)

This may help fix your error : [How to fix IE select issue when dynamically changing options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942681/how-to-fix-ie-select-issue-when-dynamically-changing-options)

Other onChange events work fine with IE11.

This is an example posted by [user2744722](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2744722/user2744722):

```html
<p>Select a different option in the drop-down listbox to trigger the <strong>onchange</strong> event.</p>
<select name="selTest" onchange="alert('Index: ' + this.selectedIndex + '\nValue: ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <option value="Books">Books</option>
  <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
  <option value="Housewares">Housewares</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The selected option is not changed programatically. I'm having static values for selected options and added the onchangeevent in document ready function.

Comment: Normal onChange works fine on IE 11. Post your code, if you are facing a problem.